# Apache server Forbidden php

Tags: php, apache, http

I just got a VPS and it's running CentOS 6.8 with WHM 58.0. I really don't want the WHM, I only want to add one site to the server. So I just installed an FTP server and uploaded the files to the Apache root dir at `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` and gave all files `chmod 777`.

All works good, but when I go to PHP or ajax to PHP I get "403 Forbidden". I suppose the problem is in the `http.config` but I really have no idea. Here is my [http.conf file](http://textuploader.com/dsil8) and I don't have any `.htaccess` files.

Comment: What Does the error log say exactly?

Comment: it just don't allow the access to php file or run them ---- 403 forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just  replace this

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

With this

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
Options Indexes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, you want to make sure that the Linux user that is running Apache has permission to read and execute the PHP files where they are on the server.

This is a good guide for transferring PHP files and setting the permissions using PHP: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server

There's also a guide here to setting up the server and checking that PHP is set up correctly here, but I assume you have done this already: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04